# App Engine: Where to store html - datastore or cloud storage

Tags: php, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, google-cloud-storage

i'm automatically creating an html page, storing it with a unique identifier, and than displaying it whenever someone visits http://www.example.com/view/unique_identifier.

Where should I store the html page, the datastore or cloud storage? If it's the datastore, than the unique identifier is the key, and I just fetch and serve the html. If it's cloud storage, the file is named with the unique identifier, I just serve it.

What's faster? What are advantages and disadvantages for either method in the long run?

I'm using PHP on App Engine.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Always use cloud storage - there's two scenarios for you here.

- If you want to implement some type of access control on the html file before serving it.

Put it in cloud storage and use CloudStorageTools::serve() to serve the file, after checking the user has access.

This allows you to have html files of *any* size in cloud storage - it also makes you app more efficient as the files are not served by your instance but buy the app engine infrastructure. You PHP script would look like

```
<?php

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
CloudStorageTools::serve('gs://my_bucket/unique_identifier.html');
```

- The pages are public - you just want to serve them.

Put the page in Google Cloud Storage and then return a 301 or 302 redirect to the page from the app - Cloud Storage will put in the correct caching headers so users will get the pages faster once they are in the edge cache etc.

Your php script might look like

```
<?php

use google\appengine\api\cloud_storage\CloudStorageTools;
header('Location: ' . CloudStorageTools::getPublicUrl('gs://my_bucket/unique_identifier.html'));
```

Note: You can still do (1) with a public page if you don't want users to have to make 2 requests to get the page.

Comment: Maybe NOT always use cloudstorage. Because (from the docs): You can use a CNAME redirect only with HTTP, not with HTTPS !! This one will not work: h ttps://www.example.com/view/unique_identifier.

Comment: In which case you use CloudStorageTools::serve like I said in the answer.

Comment: I accepted this answer and went with cloud storage because the html will never change, and I do like that it takes the load off my instances. Will it make sense to use memcache to speed it up?

Comment: i'm not sure why you think you need memcache - unless it's to map the unique identifier to the file name.

Comment: I think you would be fine serving it from your instance too. If you set proper cache directives(which you have to do on cloud storage anyway) the content is cached by the appengine frontend servers so it won't hit your instances very often. GCS has its own issues(i.e. fragmentation/portability and reliability)

Answer (score 1):

Use Datastore to keep HTML pages as data content for the following reasons:

- HTML documents are mostly small enough not to need Cloud Storage (< 1MB)
- Page URLs will be what you name them, in the domain name of the application
- Apps can

  - speed retrieval with Memcache
  - optionally process HTML pages as templates
  - apply finer grained, context sensitive access control
  - perform dynamically variable redirects
  - let users with permissions edit the HTML within the app itself

Answer (score 0):

Cloud Storage is much cheaper. That's the only substantial difference for your use case.

Comment: I think it depends by usage. The price/request is smaller on datastore.

Comment: There is no fee "per request" in cloud storage (standard option).

Comment: Of course it is.  :)  Currently the fee per op is  $0.10 or $0.01 depending by the its class).

Comment: Can you provide a link?

Comment: 1. These are for JSON/XML API calls, not user requests when user browsers load a resource. 2. These are per 10,000 ops, not per op.  In the Datastore users cannot load the resource directly, so every call has to go through your instance and counts for billing.

Comment: You are right about price/ops. That was a typo. However as I said: same pricing applies for direct fetch of the object[0]. There is no "free" operation. I'm aware that the requests need a broker/instance to pass the data from datastore but as I said with proper caching directives and based on usage datastore may be a better solution. [0] ``Serving content incurs storage costs for hosting the content (per GB per Month), network egress (per GB), and retrieval operations (Class B). See the Google Cloud Storage pricing page for more details. `` http://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/static-website –

Answer (score 0):

As usual it dependson your use case.

- How big are these HTML files?
- Do you plan to alter these files?
- Will you NEED access control?
- do you need to reuse this data from another app?

Don't add unnecessary complexity to your app because this framework or this service offers functionalities you don't actually need.

If what you need is simple, go with @Martin Berends 's answer.